# Comparing Four Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two lists in a spreadsheet. Both lists consist of two columns. One column is computer serial numbers and the other column is the person that the computer from the first column is assigned to.

The lists were created by two different people and I need to compare them and find discrepancies. Here's an example of this problem: [image: Example].

In this example I would need to make sure that Person A has been assigned CPU1 in both dataset A and dataset B. If there is a discrepancy then dataset B should take precedence. However, if there is a person that is present in dataset A that is not present in dataset B, that person should remain in the list.

Comment: `Index/match` will probably do what you want. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to ccheck List A's vis-a-vis List B, changing to match List B where needed and using List A's data where not. And presumably you'd like to know about issues that occur.

Concerning the first part, you need a new column in List A, best inserted between the two existing columns so it immediately becomes part of any range or other reference anywhere in the spreadsheet, then the column it pushed to the right Cut and Inserted before it instead of being left after it so you are back to the original material with a new column just to their right, yet the new column is part of any reference to List A's material.

For the second, there are at least two events that one suspects would interest you: 1) List A has data that does not match List B. The result in the column is the "correct-er" List B, but there is a mismatch, and 2) After doing the check, the result shown is a duplicate of other results shown. In other words, you show at least two Persons assigned to a particular CPU and unless List B contains duplicates, this is because List B says one person and List A shows one or more others as having that CPU. Only the List B result Person can be correct so the others represent problems.

To do the checking work, insert the new column, then move the column that got pushed right back in place. I'll say your data is currently List A is columns A and B, the black column is column C, and List B is columns D and E. Ending up you'll have a new column C pushing all the others one column to the right, so List B is now columns E and F. Header row is row 1 in the spreadsheet, and I'll pretend data is rows 2:11.

Since List B overrides any difference with List A, the formula will lookup each person in List A in List B and return whatever List B has, if it has an entry for that person and return what List A has if there is no List B entry:

```
XLOOKUP($B2,$F$2:$F$5,$E$2:$E$5,$A2,0,1)
```

Used the nice, new `XLOOKUP()` but if you do not have it, you'll need an `Index/Match` solution since you have to "look left" in List B.

Then the problems. You have at least two choices in how to handle them. Probably others, like you could write a macro to do it, but I'll just think formulas. One way is to complicate that nice `XLOOKUP()` with tests for the problem. Most people seem to grwon loudly and head off that way. But there is a vastly easier way, one that allows a ton of fine-tuning if it would be desired though you just need the basics here. It is to use Conditional Formatting ("CF") to do the testing rather than make that formula above into a 20 line monster you don't truly understand even when you're just finished.

With CF you only need choose the order of how you list the rules so they are tested in an order that works right. (Most people figure the tests first. If you choose the order first, you have to then work out tests that will fit that order. Usually lots easier to go the other way so folks do.)

So, if there are more than one Persons listing a particular CPU now, that's called "duplicates" and CF has a built-in rule for that. Easy to test it first, so set that up. I'll get to the format to apply in a moment, 'cause there's a "trick" with it. Then make a second rule that uses this formula for its test:

```
=XLOOKUP($B2,$F$2:$F$5,$E$2:$E$5,$A2,0,1)<>$A2
```

Notice that this new rule inserts itself before duplicates rule. That's all good, these won't work if you move this down to being the second rule checked. DO check the "Stop if True" box.

Now CF will check to see if the result of the formula matches the original List A data for the Person. If it does, it will apply the format here and stop. If not it goes on to the second rule.

The second rule checks to see if there is duplication and applies the format for that if there is.

So, the "trick"... you will use a pretty infrequent formatting possibility to put the error messages into the new List A results (rather than doing the nightmares of fitting them into the cell's formula, the nightmare of work and the nightmare of ever trying to understand it all again for updating or correcting it).

The normal numerical formatting allows you to set formatting for up to four KINDS of data in a cell: postive numbers, negative numbers, zeroes, and text. In any of them, you can put text strings (plural) into the format. In fact, a format can be nothing BUT a text string. For both of these CF rules, you will use this fact. For the first rule, use the following, exactly as you see it:

;;;"List A mismatch"

and for the second rule, use the following:

;;;">1 assigned"

To make those stand out better (they are longer text than the "CPU" text but...), you might format the text a different color, at least, perhaps a nice red.

And if you just need the list with no problems noted, just do the formula at the start and remember this CF stuff for another day when you'd like a simple, straightforward formula in your cells and all the testing for errors and giving appropriate messages in simple rules in CF instead of making the cell formulas nightmares.